# Why is my html element shifted to the left or right?

Tags: html, offset

The html:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<section id="content"></section>
</body>
</html>
```

The css:

```
html, 
body { margin: 0; }

#content { 
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The entire page contents  is shifted to the left or right. No css margin, left, right indications of the page being offset. What could this be?!

It was the scrollLeft value! A javascript function was updating the scrollLeft property of the html element.

Comment: more information ? link to page? code ?

Comment: Could be many things. Please post some code.

Comment: Hey mechanic, good to have you on the phone. Sometimes my car works, sometimes it doesnt.. Can you tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your scrollLeft value, A javascript function is updating the scrollLeft property of the html element.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your website is in a certain  that may be aligned left? That would cause a problem like this.